# Can't get 'Inbox' folder via Microsoft Graph api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I can't get 'Inbox' mailFolder resource via Microsoft Graph api.

I tried to use `/me/mailFolders` to get all of mailFolders under the root folder, but the 'Inbox' didn't show in api response.

Besides, I also tried to send api with the well-known folder names, but the server responded `ErrorItemNotFound`.

However, there are many sub-folders under my 'Inbox' mail folder, and I can see them via Office365 website.

Here are the detail request and response.

Request:

```
GET /users/5df7dac4-5c93-4bb6-8dc9-7bdf586c3e97/mailFolders/inbox
```

Response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "ErrorItemNotFound",
    "message": "The specified object was not found in the store.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "7a5904ba-cf58-4278-aab4-937176ef2a45",
      "date": "2019-01-21T08:23:22"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `/me/mailfolders/inbox` should return the correct `mailFolder`. If it isn't, it is likely something specific to your mailbox/tenant. To resolve something like that, you'd want to open a support ticket with Microsoft.

Comment: I cant reproduce this. `/v1.0/me/mailFolders` does return Inbox as part of the list (it's not always the first in the list) and `/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox` does correctly return the Inbox folder object.  As does `/v1.0/users/000000-0000-0000-0000-c0edaa52b861/mailFolders/inbox`.

Comment: @RichardFuller The api does not work only on this account. The others receive correct response. Can you test the api using this account again?

Comment: I don't have access to that account.  Could you try using the [Exchange REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/mail-rest-operations) directly with the account and seeing if the folders are visible there?  You confirmed that they are visible in OWA and Outlook too right?

Comment: @RichardFuller Outlook REST Version 2.0 does not return INBOX either, but I can get the inbox information from [EWS api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/ee693005(v%3Dexchg.80))

Comment: I've seen this with one of our "new" user's mailboxes that have not been accessed yet by the user. Once the user logged in via the office.com portal and accessed their mailbox we were able to query `/mailFolders` successfully