# I can't seem to get 'Inbox' and 'Sent Items' folders using Microsoft Graph API

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

I am unable to get the Inbox and Sent items folders when I print all my folders. But I am able to get other folders including the custom folders I have added. Here's my code that calls the api -

```
url = f"/users/{self.emailId}/mailFolders"
method = "get"
result = self._request.makeRequest(method=method,url=url)
```

My question is similar to the one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54288794/cant-get-inbox-folder-via-microsoft-graph-api) but there's no solution to that either. And I am using an Ubuntu system so MFCMAPI won't work.

Comment: It works for me. Alternate you can try the same Graph API "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailfolders" call in Microsoft Graph Explorer as well. It works for me too.

Comment: Also you can test the same with POSTMAN too.

Comment: Hi @Dev, I ran it in Microsoft Graph explorer and I am still missing the Inbox and Sent Items folder, do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: That's weird. I believe you used the above API call, right? I tested with Graph Explorer and POSTMAN - it works. Also i tested with my personal account (hotmail) and work/school (office 365)account too.

Comment: I am not aware of any restriction from Graph API perspective, unless the programmer implemented anything. If the issue persists then i would suggest you to connect with Microsoft Support for further investigation.

Comment: Yes @Dev I did, and I used `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox` to check if there was any error but the response is correct, only when listing all the folders 'inbox' doesn't show up.

Comment: Also make sure that the mailbox is ever logged in by a given user and able to access the mailbox. If not, i would recommend the user to sign-in the mailbox, make sure they can able to send/receive emails. That's a worth stuff to give a try.

Comment: I basically needed the 'inbox' id in my application so I found a workaround and retrieved the id using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/inbox/id`. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 0):

there is the limit of 10 folders returned, you should add '?top=50' and it will return more folders (had same issue where several folders where not displayed)

```
url = f"/users/{self.emailId}/mailFolders?top=50"
```